# react js cron jobs how to set in fixed time date

Tags: reactjs, cron, cron-task

There is no solution for React to support cron jobs. Could you please share your solutions/alternatives for scheduling events in React?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something which will create events without user interaction, you can always use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) which will repeatedly call the given function after the delay given in milliseconds expires.

React event handling is very similar to DOM event handling, basically instead of `onclick` and `onmouseover` you just use their camelCase version: `onClick`, `onMouseOver`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html.

Comment: `setInterval` calls the function after the given delay expires.  Depending on what precision you need you could set up a `setInterval` callback which is called in every 5 minutes, which checks the current time. If the current time matches the time you specified you show the alarm.

Comment: Any possibility to write every Sunday 9 am call method

Comment: Yes, using the method I described above.